# JQuery Colorbox In Colorbox - Resize Parent in when child resizes

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, iframe, colorbox

I have a scenario and I have spent hours trying different things (I am fairly new to JQuery) and I wonder if someone could point me in the right direction.

I have a colorbox dialog ("Dialog 1") , which then opens another colorbox dialog inside the first ("Dialog 2").  I can resize Dialog 2 to fit its contents, but occasionally the content is bigger than Dialog 1 so I need to resize Dialog 1 from Dialog 2 (so it is say xx pixels larger).  Can anyone help?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Please be sure to include any code that might be useful for anyone trying to help you. Even if you don't think it would be that useful it's important to show that you have made an effort

Answer (score 2):

To dynamically re-size color-box you want to say.

```
colorbox.resize({width:"500px" height:"500px"})
```

If you want to re-size a color box that loads an I-frame you would add something like this to  the head of your target document.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = $('mydiv').height();
    var y = $('mydiv').width();
    parent.$.colorbox.resize({width:y, height:x});
});
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: You don't need to pass parameters to `resize`.